# How long does it take the Predator UAV to reach cruise altitude?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, climb, vertical-speed, load-factor

For applications such as UAVs, especially military ones like the Predators and Reapers, do the same regulations as light aircraft apply due to their structure?
Or, does the absence of a human operator enable a higher rate of climb and descent? How long would the UAV traditionally take to climb to its cruising altitude then?

Comment: It's an interesting question title, but there are three separate questions being asked. Could you bring some more focus to this question and concentrate on just one part? You can always ask the other parts as separate questions.

Comment: Naïvely, I wouldn't expect that the climb rate could be greater than the engine power divided by the weight of the drone, which for a fully loaded Predator (using the [specs from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Atomics_MQ-1_Predator#Specifications)) works out to about 1700 feet per minute.  There may be some subtleties of aeronautical engineering that I'm not taking into account, though.

Comment: Aircraft are aircraft, humans in the aircraft are just another issue that affects performance.  UAV's don't generally have fixed cruise altitudes, it all depends on the mission parameters.